# mongodb count num of distinct values for each object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate-functions

Hello i am creating a new Web Application for products selling  using MEAN stack and i want  to see for every brand (HP,ASUS..) how many pc have 8 Gb , how many PC have 4 GB etc.
so this is my code

```
exports.allcountProduct = async (req, res) => {
try {
    const count = await Product.aggregate(

            {
                "$group": {
                    "_id": {
                        $toLower: "$ram"
                    },
                    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
                }
            },
            {
                "$group": {
                    "_id": null,
                    "counts": { "$push": { "k": "$_id", "v": "$count" } }
                }
            },
            {
                "$replaceRoot": {
                    "newRoot": { "$arrayToObject": "$counts" }
                }
            },

        ],

    )

    res.json(count);
}
```

and what im getting is :

```
 [
{
    "4GB": 20,
    "8GB": 15,
    "16GB": 32
}
```

]

so im getting is the results of all the brands while what im trying to get is every brand alone like this :

```
   [
{
    "brand": "ASUS",
    "8GB": 6,
    "16GB": 14
}
```

]

this is an example from the document :

```
{
"_id":ObjectID( "617b0dbacda6cbd1a0403f68")
"brand": "6178524a5ff14e633aeff1ea",
"SerialNumber": "45454234324",
"ram": "4gb",
},
{
"_id":ObjectID( "617b0dbacda6cbd1a040345")
"brand": "6178524a5ff14e633aeff1ea",
"SerialNumber": "azazz5245454az",
"ram": "8gb",
},
```

Comment: it will help if you add original document structure as it is not clear where the brand is located ...

Comment: @R2D2
`{
    "_id":ObjectID( "617b0dbacda6cbd1a0403f68")
    "brand": "6178524a5ff14e633aeff1ea",
    "SerialNumber": "45454234324",
    "ram": "4gb",
    },
    {
    "_id":ObjectID( "617b0dbacda6cbd1a040345")
    "brand": "6178524a5ff14e633aeff1ea",
    "SerialNumber": "azazz5245454az",
    "ram": "8gb",
    },`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
mongos> db.b.aggregate([
{$group:{ _id:{ r:"$ram" ,b:"$brand"}, cnt:{$sum:1} }}  ,
{$project:{ a:[{k:"$_id.r" ,v:"$cnt"}] , brand:"$_id.b" ,_id:0}   },
{$project:{d:{$arrayToObject:"$a"} ,brand:1 }  } ,
{$group:{ _id:"$brand", ram:{$push:"$d"}  }} ,
{$project:{_id:0,brand:"$_id" ,"options": { $mergeObjects: "$ram" } }},
{$replaceRoot: {  newRoot: { $mergeObjects: ["$$ROOT", "$options"] }}}, 
{$project:{options:0}}   ]).pretty()

{ "brand" : "6178524a5ff14e633aeff1ea", "8gb" : 1, "4gb" : 1 }
{ "brand" : "sony", "16gb" : 2, "8gb" : 1 }
mongos>
```

explained:

1. group by ram and brand  so we count how much per brand per ram size
2. project the ram type and ram count to k & v suitable for next stage to join as object
3. Convert k,v arrays to object
4. Group by brand so we can have a list per ram size & count
5. Switch the array with ram types/counts to object
6. Flatten the object to the root object
7. project only the needed fields as per our needs

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sglsKwVKc4P)

Comment: thank it works fine but couldt find a solution  to add the sum like this  itried to project $sum but result always 0 i want it to look like this     { "brand" : "sony", "16gb" : 2, "8gb" : 1, "sum" :3}

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/MhKcfcD4bvJ

Comment: ive tried it but its given wrong sum same in your example sony sum should be 2 but its 3

Comment: aaah my mistake I misunderstood , thought you need sum of objects ...

Comment: its giving the highest sum every time i think

Comment: Its giving 3 every time

Comment: this is because you have only 8gb & 16gb + brand

Comment: What im trying to add is the sum of brand how many sony andbthen how many 8gb and how many 4gb

Comment: ah nice I just saw Takis solved it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70200211/mongodb-count-number-of-distinct-values-and-the-sum-of-each-object